# CPU Credit Balance are limited in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I Stopped the Instance for 24 hours to collect more cpu credit But it frozen in 35

It should add 6 credit every hour (144 credit after 24 hour) But frozen in 35
(Type of Instance : t2.micro)

Comment: Can you explain me more please

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi according to [CPU Credits and Baseline Performance for Burstable Performance Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html), T2 credits do not persist between instance start and stop unlike T3 instance.

> **Accrued CPU Credits Life Span**
>
> CPU credits on a running instance do not expire.
>
> For T3, the CPU credit balance persists for seven days after an instance stops and the credits are lost thereafter. If you start the instance within seven days, no credits are lost.
>
> For T2, the CPU credit balance does not persist between instance stops and starts. If you stop a T2 instance, the instance loses all its accrued credits.